# iOS video player w/added audio channel for guitar play along

Tags: ios, audio, video, input, playback

I'm researching doing play alongs with instructional videos which intentionally play at normal speed, then slow it down.  It would be great if on an iPad or iPhone add an input/monitoring channel with level controls for play along with Guitar/Bass.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iOS called iPractice that you might want to take a look at. It plays guitar lessons at different speeds. It comes with a set of lessons, but you can't add your own.